# Predefined text directly posted on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, post

i am using facebook android sdk provided for facebook i m using their examples-simple provided by them and its working very finely , now on login in fb show a form from fb to post on wall on button click .
but I want to set text directly from code and on button click it directly post the text set by me on fb without calling the wall post form to enter the text and share .

[image: this is my project image conatning all fb related files that i m using]

this is my project image conatning all fb related files that i m using and beloow is mu step wise o/p of this project

1.login

[image]

[image]

after clcik show share form

[image]

but after wall post i want to directly upload my post on fb how can i do this  and what to change i am not getting any idea i tried but cannot set my predefined text ,how cani directly post on wall without calling the form to share 
i have downloaded sdk fron gitstore from this link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/  pls help me thanks in advance

this is my example.java code

```
      mUploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("method", "photos.upload");

                URL uploadFileUrl = null;
                try {
                    uploadFileUrl = new URL(
                        "http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)uploadFileUrl.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();
                    int length = conn.getContentLength();

                    byte[] imgData =new byte[length];
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    is.read(imgData);
                    params.putByteArray("picture", imgData);

                } catch  (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST",
                        new SampleUploadListener(), null);
            }
        });
        mUploadButton.setVisibility(mFacebook.isSessionValid() ?
                View.VISIBLE :
                View.INVISIBLE);

        mPostButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mFacebook.dialog(Example.this, "feed",
                        new SampleDialogListener());
            }
        });
        mPostButton.setVisibility(mFacebook.isSessionValid() ?
                View.VISIBLE :
                View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public class SampleAuthListener implements AuthListener {

        public void onAuthSucceed() {
            mText.setText("You have logged in! ");
            mRequestButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mUploadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPostButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onAuthFail(String error) {
            mText.setText("Login Failed: " + error);
        }
    }

    public class SampleLogoutListener implements LogoutListener {
        public void onLogoutBegin() {
            mText.setText("Logging out...");
        }

        public void onLogoutFinish() {
            mText.setText("You have logged out! ");
            mRequestButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mUploadButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mPostButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            try {
                // process the response here: executed in background thread
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                final String name = json.getString("name");

                // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
                // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
                // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
                // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
                Example.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mText.setText("Hello there, " + name + "!");
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            try {
                // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                final String src = json.getString("src");

                // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
                // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
                // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
                // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
                Example.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mText.setText("Hello there, photo has been uploaded at \n" + src);
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    public class WallPostRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Got response: " + response);
            String message = "<empty>";
            try {

                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                message = json.getString("lithe Technologies");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            final String text = "Your Wall Post: " + message + "helloooo lithe";
            Example.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mText.setText(text);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class WallPostDeleteListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            if (response.equals("true")) {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Successfully deleted wall post");
                Example.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mText.setText("Deleted Wall Post");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Could not delete wall post");
            }
        }
    }


    public class SampleDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
                mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());
                mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new Bundle(), "DELETE",
                                new WallPostDeleteListener(), null);
                    }
                });
                mDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "No wall post made");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write below two functions into your Activity.

```
public void postToWall() {
    String message="Good Morning to All";
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);
    parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
    try {
        facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        } else {
            showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

2)

```
public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
    facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
    return facebook.isSessionValid();
}
```

3)

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

Write below code into your wall post button click event

```
facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
restoreCredentials(facebook);
if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
    loginAndPostToWall();
} else {
    postToWall();
}
```

Comment: I am facing same problem..and also request and authorize functions are deprecated..is there any other way ??

Comment: @PankajKushwaha First post your question with more description in stack overflow and then give me link of that question.

Comment: My questiosn is a sub-set of above question. I havent asked it anywhere on this forum.  I am using facebook.dialog method with a dialog listener to publish feeds on my faceook wall. But I dont want to use dialog and post it diretcly without showing dilaog. I saw that we can use facebook.request method from asyncfacebookrunner, but that is depracted and its not working for me. So, needed some alternative to do the task, i.e. dont want to show dilaog box and post directly on fb wall

Comment: @DipakKeshariya is this filling SAY SOMETHING ABOUT THIS section?! i dont think so...cause looks like its sharing the application and not filling the ABOYT part...

Comment: @MahdiGiveie I don't Understand your comment.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya 
Do u see the "Write Something" in the Dialog? i want to fill that part! how can i do that? i mean instead of letting user to write what he wants , just fill by our self

Comment: @MahdiGiveie Sorry but i don't know about this.